# Iterate through each menu item into a shortcode

Tags: menus, shortcode

Since i cant easily use short-codes in the menu, is there a simple way to iterate through all a menus label through a short-code?

For example say i created a few custom link menus with labels of home, aboutus, contact and i wanted to fetch these labels and sent it through a short-code and have the menu use the output of the short-code for each menu item.

Comment: I am not totally sure I understand but I thank what you're looking for is a [Custom Walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker)

Answer (score 0):

Skimming through the core file, there are some quick & dirty ways available (untested):

- `! is_admin() && add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items',        'do_shortcode' );`
- `! is_admin() && add_filter( 'the_title',                'do_shortcode' );`
- `! is_admin() && add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'do_shortcode' );`

But I would rather target the menu labels directly with for example (untested):

```
/**
 * Support shortcodes in the menu labels
 */
! is_admin() && add_action( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpse_shortcode_in_menu' );

function wpse_shortcode_in_menu( $atts )
{
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_do_shortcode' );
    return $atts;
}

function wpse_do_shortcode( $content )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return do_shortcode( $content );
}
```